# Display multiple Images like Instagram app [ just like in post horizontally]

Tags: android-studio, imageview, instagram, photo

i want to display the some set of images horizontally like Instagram app implemented

Example : [example is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZuLuhKHUjw6ruBIeSbipFQX66T1VQLN4/view?usp=sharing)

how i can achieve this , help me.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Use ViewPager with page indicator.

Answer (score 2):

If its just a single view on your screen where you have to show an image slider like that, you can simply use a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager and you can set the orientation as horizontal.

If its a list of such Image slider views, you can use a RecyclerView and can use a ViewPager in every row item.

Comment: you will get better output using ViewPager with page indicator , since i need to display multiple image like instagram app